# Using CASE with non-integer values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am building a query for a report in my network inventory system LanSweeper. The is the minimal example to show my what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Select Distinct Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetName,
  (Select Case When tblRegistry.Value = 2 Then 'Notify Only'
      When tblRegistry.Value = 3 Then 'Download Notify'
      When tblRegistry.Value = 4 Then 'Scheduled'
      When tblRegistry.Value = 5 Then 'Download and Custom'
      Else tblRegistry.Value End As RegistryValue
  From tblAssets As TA Left Join tblRegistry On tblRegistry.AssetID = TA.AssetID
  Where tblRegistry.Valuename = 'AUoptions' And TA.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID)
  As AUOption
From tblAssets
```

The issue is that table `tblRegistry` is a collection of registry keys and values that I have told my system to inventory. There is a mix of strings and integers in that table since I am inventorying several keys for other reports. I am having no issues pulling the values I want out of the table. My issue is stemming from trying to give friendly strings for the numerical values. In the case above for Automatic Update settings on Windows computers.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'C62E10' to data type int
```

This makes sense since it is obviously not an integer. It would seem that all `tblRegistry.Value`'s are being evaluated by the `CASE` instead of the ones that would have been filtered out be the `WHERE` clase `Where tblRegistry.Valuename = 'AUoptions'`

Is there a way to filter out non-numerical values from the `CASE` statement?

Comment: How about using varchar in `case... when`? `Case When tblRegistry.Value = '2' Then ...`

Comment: How about `CASE WHEN CAST(tblRegistry.Value AS INT) = 2`

Comment: What is the underlying datatype of `tblRegistry.Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the `tblRegistry.Value` is `nvarchar` but it happens that some values are numeric.
If you use integers in `case` then you force the DBMS convert to your type and that is not possible in some cases. Use varchar instead, so it will have to compare strings:

```
Select Distinct Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetName,
(Select Case When tblRegistry.Value = '2' Then 'Notify Only'
  When tblRegistry.Value = '3' Then 'Download Notify'
  When tblRegistry.Value = '4' Then 'Scheduled'
  When tblRegistry.Value = '5' Then 'Download and Custom'
  Else tblRegistry.Value End As RegistryValue
From tblAssets As TA Left Join tblRegistry On tblRegistry.AssetID = TA.AssetID
Where tblRegistry.Valuename = 'AUoptions' And TA.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID)
As AUOption
From tblAssets
```

Comment: Didn't think the other data mattered since it was being filtered. Obviously is is all being tested. This worked for me. Now I don't have to tell people what 4 is. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where are you filtering them. There is a `where` but the column being tested is `Valuename` not `value`. Does your data 'guarantee' that you'll have numeric values when `valuename = 'AUoptions'`?

Comment: After reading your comment and thinking about it no... I'm not filtering it at all. Just pulling the value from the associated valuename. Thanks again for the help. Only delve in SQL once in a blue moon.